# ASP.NET: XLSX file is being corrupted in Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

When opening the XLSX file after downloading, I get the error message in Excel:

> We found a problem with some content in '*filename.xlsx*'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?  If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

When I check file on the server, I don't get any errors in Excel.

I'm using ASP.NET to send the file to the user as shown below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=\"filename.xlsx\"");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", File.ReadAllBytes(xlsxFilepath).Length);
    Response.TransmitFile(xlsxFilepath);
    Response.End();
}
```

This issue only started happening when I changed servers.

Comment: What is your program doing? When is this message "We found problem..." showing  What is the correlation with code that you've posted ?

Comment: When you visit the page, it downloads the XLSX, and when you open that XLSX file, Excel shows that error message.

Comment: We don't know   what file you are transmiting and clearly there is some folblem with thic file

Comment: But if I open the file on the server, I don't get any errors - I only get errors after the file has been downloaded from this page and the file is not being modified in anyway in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed `Response.Flush()` before `Response.End()`